# Unable to enlarge text box, and align the words in one line instead of forming 2 lines

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to enlarge the text box with input-lg but it doesn't work, it remained the same. Also, the text overflowed to the next line, trying to make them align into a single line next to the text box.

```html
       <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">

                        <form class="form-horizontal" id="step2">
                            <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label col text-right" ><b>Email:</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input id="name" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label col text-right" ><b>New Password:</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input id="name" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your New Password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label col text-right" ><b>Role:</b></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <select class="form-control input-lg" id="selectStaff">
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label col text-right" ><b>Created At:</b></label>
                                <div class='col-sm-4'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control input-lg" id='datetimepicker4' />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label col text-right" ><b>Updated At:</b></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input id="name" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your New Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Done</button>
                    </div>      
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of bootstrap you are using? Bootstrap 4 has no `input-lg` class. I have added the latest bootstrap 4.5.0 on your code.

I modified the `col-sm-2` to `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-4` to `col-sm-8` to adjust the width for label and input text.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal-body form-horizontal">

  <form class="form-horizontal" id="step2">
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-right"><b>Email:</b></label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input id="name" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-right"><b>New Password:</b></label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input id="name" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your New Password" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-right"><b>Role:</b></label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control input-lg" id="selectStaff">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-right"><b>Created At:</b></label>
      <div class='col-sm-8'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control input-lg" id='datetimepicker4' />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label col text-right"><b>Updated At:</b></label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input id="name" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your New Password" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Done</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the text is in a single line and its working now. but for the input lg, I've a version 4.4.1 bootstrap link and after replacing it with the 4.5.0, it doesn't change a thing and remained the same size, also changing my layout for the design.

Comment: Bootstrap 4.5.0 has no input-lg class. I back-traced and found it is only available in Bootstrap 3 (The version i checked was 3.3.7).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion to mislead you that Bootstrap 4.5.0 has input-lg class

Comment: Does that mean that, 4.4.1 works too? or do I have to revert it to an older version? is there anyway to make adjust the text box with the current version?

Comment: col-sm-* will work in version 4.4.1 too. We don't need to use input-lg if we use col-sm-4 and col-sm-8